# Get yesterday's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This may be an obvious question but im new to ruby and I've spent ages trying to get yesterdays date for a cucumber test that checks a url that includes yesterday's date. for example:
http://www.blah.co.uk/blah/blah/schedule/2011-11-28

I've created the following within my helper methods:

```
def Helper.get_date
  Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') / 1.day
end
```

But it doesn’t like the `/1.day` or `– 1.day` or `– 86400` (seconds).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(Date.today-1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Would be a non rails-specific way.

Comment: Date.yesterday.to_s works if you want the date in GMT time.  (Date.today-1).to_s may also suite your needs.  There are subtle differences depending on your timezone.

Answer (score 9):

You can use some of the methods in ActiveSupport (which will be included if you're in a Rails app) to do the following:

```
DateTime.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

EDIT:
As it's a standard date format, you could also reference the standard directly:

```
DateTime.yesterday.iso8601
```

Comment: +1 for referencing [`DateTime#iso8601`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answers here, I think its worth while to point out the quintessential Ruby on Rails helper methods for Integers and Numerics:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > 1.days.ago
=> Tue, 29 Nov 2011 04:55:21 UTC +00:00 

ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > 1.month.ago
=> Sun, 30 Oct 2011 04:55:54 UTC +00:00 

ruby-1.8.7-p352 :004 > 1.week.from_now
=> Wed, 07 Dec 2011 04:56:17 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
def Helper.get_date
  (Time.now / 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end
```

Because you are decrease date not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Date.yesterday should work:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > Date.yesterday.to_s
 => "2011-11-29"
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :002 > "#{ Date.yesterday }"
 => "2011-11-29"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like

```
def Helper.get_date
  (Time.now - 60*60*24).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end
```

This is a good reference to arguments that strftime can take:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: No reason to do it this way when much easier methods exist.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser An appropriate comment. However, as this answer is still _correct_ (not misleading or broken) I would advocate upvoting other answers, not downvoting this one. _Assuming you were one of the downvotes._

Comment: Yes, I was one of the downvotes. I think this answer is misleading: it implies that this is the best way to do it. It's also broken: thanks to leap seconds, not every day is exactly 86400 seconds long (weird but true).